# For a report, in my TOC, how can I keep a period after my chapter number but not after my appendix character?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Foo}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

I would like my table of contents to be

```
1. Introduction        2
Appendix A Foo         3
```

It currently is

```
1. Introduction        2
Appendix A. Foo        3
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tocloft` gives a hidden clue: You can write additional commands into the toc file at the beginning of the appendix.  When the table of contents is displayed, the additional commands are executed and change the design.  In this case, the following does the trick:

```
\begin{appendices}
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapaftersnum}{}}
   \chapter{Foo}
\end{appendices}
```

The `\protect` is necessary, since otherwise TeX expands the macros `\renewcommand` or `\cftchapaftersnum`.